# Selenium waitforpopup executing before page full loaded

Tags: selenium

I am attempting to grab source html for a popup (using waitForPopUp and getHtmlSource); however, selenium is not waiting for the popup to fully load with the target content, thus I am getting the code for the call to get the content (please let me know what the actual term is for that).

Can someone tell me which selenium function I can use to make the script wait for the target to load before grabbing the source?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`clickAndWait`, `waitForPageToLoad` and `open` are only a few examples of function you can use to wait for a main page to fully load. They are blocking, so call `waitForPopUp` immediately afterwards.

Comment: Should I be assigning a target to my popup, or will selenium know that it is whatever popup comes up? What kind of target would I use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign window ID, and time out to it. From Selenium IDE -

```
waitForPopUp(windowID, timeout)
Arguments:

    * windowID - the JavaScript window "name" of the window that will appear (not the text of the title bar) If unspecified, or specified as "null", this command will wait for the first non-top window to appear (don't rely on this if you are working with multiple popups simultaneously).
    * timeout - a timeout in milliseconds, after which the action will return with an error. If this value is not specified, the default Selenium timeout will be used. See the setTimeout() command.

Waits for a popup window to appear and load up.
```

b/w did you support Selenium Proposal on area51 - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium
This proposal is backed by SeleniumHQ and we need more users to commit to it to make it see day of light.

Answer (score 0):

Directly after the command that caused the popup window to appear (usually `click`) run `selectPopUpAndWait`.